# Installing python packages for a custom interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

I am using a program that comes with its custom python interpreter (it is essentially python 2.7.14 with custom libraries installed). I am trying to create a plugin for this program, and need to install a third-party package for this interpreter (the package is matplotlib, but I'll probably need to add others too). How do I properly install packages for this interpreter? It does not have pip installed.

I have tried installing the package into the project folder and appending the location to sys.path, but I get the following error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Thank you for any help

Comment: Try `<path-to-interpreter>/python -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Doesn't do anything, but the interpreter doesn't have pip so I would expect that

Comment: Ah sorry, install pip first `https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installation`

Comment: i have sucessfully installed pip now, but when i try to run it the way you wrote, I get no output and no module is installed afterwards.